# How do you create a function in CSound?

Tags: function, csound

I've read the Lazzarini book and it says you can declare an opcode like this:

```
opcode EnvOsc, a, aaiiij
  amp,afr,iri,
  xout a2
endop
```

but how do you declare a function?  It's not in the book or Google